# Filter users in tenant based on an attribute value

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, graph-explorer

Running

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?select=onPremisesExtensionAttributes
```

on Graph Explorer gives the following response.

```
value": [
        {
            "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
                "extensionAttribute1": null,
                "extensionAttribute2": null,
                "extensionAttribute3": null,
                "extensionAttribute4": 1,
                "extensionAttribute5": null                
            }
        },
        {
            "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
                "extensionAttribute1": null,
                "extensionAttribute2": null,
                "extensionAttribute3": null,
                "extensionAttribute4": 2,
                "extensionAttribute5": null
            }
        },
        {
            "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
                "extensionAttribute1": null,
                "extensionAttribute2": null,
                "extensionAttribute3": null,
                "extensionAttribute4": 1,
                "extensionAttribute5": null
            }
        }
]
```

How do I update

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=onPremisesExtensionAttributes
```

to return only users with `extensionAttribute4 = 1`?

On trying

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute4 eq '1'
```

I see:

> "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery", "message": "Unsupported or invalid
> query filter clause specified for property 'extensionAttribute4' of
> resource 'User'.",

Answer (score 0):

Your filter query is correct, but it requires to add the `ConsistencyLevel:eventual` header to the request and $count query parameter.

```
/v1.0/users?$filter=onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute4 eq '1'&$count=true
```

Resources:

[Advanced query capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http)

[User properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#user-properties)